# How to determine where water is coming in basement wall

Tags: water, basement

I have an unfinished basement, that I am starting to prep to be finished. We haven't (didn't think we have) had any water issues. I did a moisture test, and it was good.

While installing new insulation I noticed this wet spot. It corresponds with a crack in the window sill. I caulked the interior crack/exterior crack with concrete caulk, but it doesn't seem to have stopped the water.

Tips/suggestions for proper-fix and determining where the water is coming in from.

I have attempted to keep my basement dry, all roof-run-off water is piped to retention pond at the far end of my yard (40+feet away from house). It has been rainy/snowy this year, so ground is quite saturated, possible water is seeping in from side instead of through crack in window sill. I don't think this is coming from below the floor.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Basement wall with arrows pointing to water spot]

[image: Image of outside window well, showing crack.]

Comment: If you want to continue with finishing, I suggest checking the outside of that wall and seal it.  Inside sealing is usually temporary at best.  This means digging, but you do not want water in a finished basement.

Comment: Yeah, given the **big** crack, the water is coming from outside the wall, through the wall, down there - not filtering down from the windowsill. And the only remotely reliable fix to a big crack in the wall is to seal the outside of it. Or take a time machine back and slap whoever said "reinforcing wasn't needed here" upside the head.

Comment: The crack (under the seal is fairly small), but I am afraid you are right, we will have to dig the outside out and repair the wall :(

Comment: I am thinking that we put some hydrolic cement on the crack/wall now, then in the spring when its less wet/my ground isn't covered in snow I dig it out and fix the outside